# NullPointerException in Fragment TabLayout when using BaseAdapter

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-listview, android-tablayout

I have successfully parsed a simple rss feed (XML feed) with background AsyncTask. But could not set the received feed from a Fragment (FragmentTOI) to a ListView using  BaseAdapter (MyBaseAdapter). Since the parsing is from fragment I used "getActivity()" instead of  "MainActivity.this". I can see all the titles in the logcat which is parsed from the rss xml feed. Code snippets and Logcat screenshot attached.

Code:

```
    // Fragment
    public static class FragmentTOI extends Fragment {
        ListView listView;
        MyAsyncTask myAsyncTask;
        Context context;
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

        public FragmentTOI(Context context) {
//            this.context = context;
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreateView (inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            View view = inflater.inflate (R.layout.fragment_toi, container, false);
            listView = view.findViewById (R.id.list_view_toi);
            startTask ();
            return view;
        }

        // Method to start the AsyncTask with new one if null.
        public void startTask() {
            //if the download is empty then cancel, else start the task
            if (myAsyncTask != null) {
                myAsyncTask.cancel (true);
            } else {
                myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask (getActivity ());
                myAsyncTask.execute ();
            }
        }

        // Method to receive data from onPostExecute of AsyncTask.
        public void receiveData(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> results) {
            Log.d ("XML", "FragmentTOI receiveData Method: " + results);
            listView.setAdapter (new MyBaseAdapter (context, results));
            listView.setAdapter (arrayAdapter);
        }
    }

    // AsyncTask downloader
    public static class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> hashMaps) {
            super.onPostExecute (hashMaps);
            fragmentTOI.receiveData (hashMaps);
        }
    }

    public static class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public MyBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
            this.data = data;
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return data.size ();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return data.get (i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            View view1 = view;
            MyRowHolder myRowHolder = null;
            if (view1 == null) {
                view1 = layoutInflater.inflate (R.layout.single_row, viewGroup, false);
                myRowHolder = new MyRowHolder (view1);
                view1.setTag (myRowHolder);
            } else {
                myRowHolder = (MyRowHolder) view1.getTag ();
            }
            HashMap<String, String> currentItem = data.get (i);
            myRowHolder.textViewTitle.setText (currentItem.get ("title"));
            return view1;
        }
    }

    static class MyRowHolder {
        TextView textViewTitle;

        public MyRowHolder(View view) {
            textViewTitle = view.findViewById (R.id.text_view_title);
        }
    }
```

Logcat: 
[image: Logcat:]

Answer (score 1):

Use `context` when you set adapter to your listview like below.

```
// Method to receive data from onPostExecute of AsyncTask.
public void receiveData(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> results) {
    //listView.setAdapter (new MyBaseAdapter (getActivity (), results)); // here you got exception.

    // use context as you initialize it inside the constructor of your fragment.
    listView.setAdapter (new MyBaseAdapter (context, results));
    listView.setAdapter (arrayAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Please post your `activity` code where you call your `FragmentTOI`.

Answer (score 1):

**Option - 1:**

Try with `requireActivity()` or `requireContext()`.

instead of

```
listView.setAdapter (new MyBaseAdapter (getActivity (), results));
```

use

```
listView.setAdapter (new MyBaseAdapter (requireActivity(), results));
```

**Option - 2:**
No need to pass `Context` in Adapter to acquire `LayoutInflater`. Remove this:

```
public MyBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
    this.data = data;
    //layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

And inside `getView` try like this:

```
if (view1 == null) {
    view1 = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate (R.layout.single_row, viewGroup, false);
    myRowHolder = new MyRowHolder (view1);
    view1.setTag (myRowHolder);
}
```

Comment: Why your fragment `static` and why you pass `Context` to call Fragment? If you need to pass `Context` then use it instead of `getActivity()`. is't it?

Comment: Try with option-2 in my answer, then let me know

Comment: When i remove the `static` this exception is occured: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.shiva.pillu.headlinessample.MainActivity.FragmentTOI must be a public static class to be  properly recreated from instance state.` And when i tried option-2 this error occurred: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment FragmentTOI{c84840f} not attached to an activity.`

Comment: Don't use this `fragmentTOI = new FragmentTOI (context);` inside AsyncTask instead use an interface to return data to fragment. You create a new instance of FragmentTOI which is not attach to activity

Comment: Please study more and refactor your code base. It's full of issues.